# Must questionnaire questions have the same number of options for IRT models to work?

Tags: item-response-theory, mirt

Given a questionnaire whose questions have different numbers of options available say having questions with ratings from 1-2 and 1-5. Could I use polytomous models such as a partial credit model to study the questionnaire data?

Comment: That's perfectly fine, though for a 1-2 item a partial credit model can be understood as a 1PL/Rasch model. You can also mix the types of IRT models fitted to each item, if the software supports such specifications.